# ternary operator never becomes true

Tags: flutter, dart, events, operators

i use a method in flutter which checks if the id of an event is equal to the current date. The purpose is to output an X if the condition is true. However, the condition is always false, even if the string of the date and the id of the stored event are exactly the same.
I have tested this with an if loop, which gives the same result.
Where is the error here?
Thanks a lot for the help.

If more code is needed, I am happy to post it.

With kind regards
Patrick

```
dateVergleich(DateTime tagesDatum) {
    final eventModelData = Provider.of<EventModelPro>(context);
    final eventModel = eventModelData.items;
    String tagesDatumString = DateFormat.yMd().format(tagesDatum);
    if (eventModel.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int x = 0; x < eventModel.length; x++) {
        tagesDatumString == eventModel[x].id ? Text('X') : Text('');
        /*if (tagesDatumString == eventModel[x].id) {
          Text('X');
        } else {
          Text('');
        }*/
        print(tagesDatum == eventModel[x].id);
        print(tagesDatumString);
        print(eventModel[x].id.toString());
      }
    }
```

the output of the debug console in VS is:

[image]

Comment: That you do `print(eventModel[x].id.toString());` is suspicious.  Is `eventModel[x].id` not already a `String`?  If not, then using `==` with a `String` will never be true.  Perhaps you mean to check `tagesDatumString == eventModel[x].id.toString()`?

Comment: with print I just wanted to check, wether the string of the dates are exactly the same, I tried tagesDatumString == eventModel[x].id.toString(), but that doesn't work as well

Comment: Please provide the exact output from the `print` statements to provide some supporting evidence that the values should compare equal.

Comment: I edited my post to show the output of the console

Comment: Your output does not show any cases where the two date strings match.  Also, it does not match your code; there should be a boolean followed by two date strings, yet the middle set contains a boolean followed by only one date (and there is an errant `2`?).  Furthermore, the value of `tagesDatumString` should be constant on each iteration of the loop, but that's not what your output shows.  Please **copy-and-paste your exact output**.  Finally, I suggest that you adjust your `print` statements to include delimiters around the printed string so that any trailing whitespace is obvious.

Comment: now I added a picture of the output. The 2 means that there are two entries with 3/26/2023 (the second and third print statement). I don't know, why this case is false as well. That tagesDatumString iterates is correct. Each day of the month the method checks, wether there is a corresponding entry in Events, where the id is the same value as the tagesDatumString. Each day the method is called.

Comment: When you say that `tagesDatumString == eventModel[x].id.toString()` doesn't work, did you change that in the ternary operator, in the `print` call, or both?  Looking at your code again, your ternary operator expression doesn't actually do anything; it creates a `Text` widget, but no reference to that widget is ever returned or saved, so it's immediately discarded. `flutter analyze` should be giving you a warning about dead code (and possibly other problems, such as using `==` on unrelated types).

Comment: I also still do not see how this output matches your code.  According to your code, on each iteration, you print `tagesDatumString` and then the event ID.  `tagesDatumString` is never reassigned within the loop.  Yet your output shows that on each iteration, the first date changes and the second date is invariant.  How do you explain that?  Please ensure that you post the *exact* code that generates the output.  Best of all would be to post a complete example that allows others to reproduce your problem.